# Docker環境でlocalhostに接続できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-mac

現在Docker環境でRuby on rails の開発をしているのですが、突然localhostへの接続ができなくなりました。

```
$ curl localhost:3000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused
```

下記、環境情報になります。

OS：macOS Sierra 10.12.6
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build: web
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - "DATABASE_HOST=db"
      - "DATABASE_PORT=5432"
      - "DATABASE_USER=＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊"
      - "DATABASE_PASSWORD=＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊"
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - "./app:/app" #共有フォルダの設定
    stdin_open: true

  db:
    image: postgres:10.1
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_USER=＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.5.0

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev postgresql-client
RUN gem install rails
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
```

原因について心当たりがある方がおりましたらご教示いただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

追記：
Docker側のポートのフォワードは正常であるため、Rails側に問題があると思われます。

```
$ docker-compose ps
     Name                    Command              State           Ports
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
db_1        docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Up      0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp
web_1       irb                             Up      0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp
```

Comment: > `突然` というと、これまではアクセスできていたのでしょうか。もしそうなら、 `docker stats` で現在も`web`コンテナが起動しているか確認してみてください。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/157014

Comment: コンテナ内からlocalhostを指定するというのは、そのコンテナ内を指しているのですよね？　そのコンテナで開いている3000番ポートの設定はどうなっているのですか？

Comment: コンテナは動いており、run web bashでコンテナ内にも入ることができる状態です。

Comment: コンテナ外部からの3000番ポートでのアクセスは内部の3000番にフォーワードされています

Answer (score 1):

`web_1`のコンテナがirbで立ち上がってますけど、サーバは動いているのでしょうか.
PumaなりWEBrickなり.

`docker-compose.yml`に`command`を追加してはどうでしょうか.

```
web:
    build: web
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "s", "-p", "3000", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
    ...
```

サーバが動いているなら、そのログを見せてください

Comment: Docker起動後にコンテナ内に入ってRailsを起動していたのですが、上記command行を追加して起動する方法に変更したところアクセスできました。回答いただきありがとうございました